# Update statement doesn't commit when using ExcuteNonQuery

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, oracleclient

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, the update statement is executed but not committed. In fact "RowsAffected" returns how many rows were affected but when checking the database, nothing has changed. I'm using commit as well

Here is my code

```
        sql = @"
                UPDATE
                    xxxx
                SET
                    xx1= '{1}',
                    xx2= '{2}',
                    xx3= '{3}',
                    xx4 = '{4}',
                    OSVERSION = '{5}',
                    FALCONVERSION = '{6}',
                    FIRMWAREVERSION = '{7}',
                    INSERVICE = '{8}'
                WHERE
                    prikey = '{0}'
           ";
        sql = string.Format(sql, id, xx1, xx2, xx3, xx4, OSVersion, FalconVersion, FirmwareVersion, InService);
```

and the part that excutes sql

```
        OracleConnection oracleConnection = new OracleConnection(ConnectionString());
        try
        {
            oracleConnection.Open();

            int rowsAffected = 0;

            OracleTransaction dbTransaction = oracleConnection.BeginTransaction();
            OracleCommand oracleCommand = new OracleCommand(sql, oracleConnection); 
            try
            {

                oracleCommand.Transaction = dbTransaction;

                rowsAffected =  oracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                dbTransaction.Commit();

                if (rowsAffected > 0)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                dbTransaction.Rollback();
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                oracleConnection.Close();
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            oracleConnection.Dispose();
        }
```

Comment: Your code *looks* okay. Are you trying to view the results directly by querying Oracle or through code? One suggestion, I would work on eliminating most of the try..catch..finally blocks in lieu of *using* statements. Checkout http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xx4z1eb6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx for an example of *using* statements...

Comment: I queried Oracle directly and through code, no changes were committed

Comment: As your primary key is a string, I suspect your Oracle collation settings to be case-sensitive. Could you please check?

Comment: No it is not string, its INT. But i always enclose all fields with single quotes. I tried without them, didn't work. When running in debug mode, i copy the sql and run in oracle sql developer, it works great. so i know for sure it's not the statement

Comment: Have you tried to remove all the carriage returns by having your SQL command fitting one line? Also please try with oracleCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

Comment: It seems i had an issue somewhere else, not in the update statement. thank you guys

Comment: Delete all the nested finally cleanup mess and use `using`.

Comment: @EGN If you post a question and find the answer eventually, either delete the question or post the answer, so that those of us in the future don't have to deal with https://xkcd.com/979/